# Scheduled task not showing dialog box

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task

We have a utility scheduled in Task Scheduler on Server 2008 R2 that just ran into an issue I haven't dealt with before.  The utility hung up (no activity for a day), and selecting end did nothing to end it, so I had to manually kill the task through task manager.  After I did, I tried running the task in debug mode from my machine, and it went through until a dialog box popped up.  Once I cleared the dialog box, the utility completed its run and exited cleanly.

The utility doesn't have any dialog boxes of its own, as it is designed to run under task scheduler, so the dialog box was a surprise to me.  It came out of an API we are using, and I took care of the issue that it presented to me, but now I want to know if it is possible to have task scheduler detect and handle these dialog boxes, or if I need to add some extra code to handle the possibility of these dialogs appearing.

Answer (score 0):

In order for these dialogs to appear, you need to run the task in the userspace. So the option: run whether or not the user is logged on cannot be used. This way, it will interact with the desktop and everything the task does is shown to the user.

This obviously means that the user must be logged in for the task to run too.

Alternatively, ensure that there are no dialog boxes.

Your question gives too little information about the program you use and where the dialog box comes from in order to help with that.